# binding data in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I'm learning angular-2 for a project and I've no idea about this error. 
This is  my html file. I want to get values from these field. Any idea

> ```
>  <form>
>   <label> Name: </label><br />
>   <input type="text" name="name"  [(ngModel)]= "user.name" /> <br/>
>   <label> Id: </label><br/>
>   <input type="number" name="Id"  [(ngModel)]= "user.Id"    /><br/>
>   <label> Email: </label><br />
>   <input type="text" name="email"  [(ngModel)]= "user.email" /><br/>
> </form>
> ```

This is in my .ts file

```
   export class UserComponent{    
   user:User;  constructor(){ } }
     }
// interface
            interface User{
                name:string;
                Id:number;
                email:string;  }
```

I can't do something like {{user.name}} on my Html file. Why is that so ? Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: you are declaring interface below this line user:User;  how in the dream the code will know that you have declared interface,put interface in a new file ,import it or place above it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be because you didn't initialize the `user` variable as an object? Try this:

```
export class UserComponent {    
  user: User = {
    name: "",
    Id: null,
    email: ""
  };
  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)). I'm a novice here. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Biken, not at all, when learning new technologies, it's OK to make newbuy mistakes ;)